# Plot Text Data in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, charts, frequency

I am trying to analyze some text data for my thesis!
How can I plot this data in *Mathematica* in a barplot based on the frequency of the words and combinations of them?

On the Abscissa (`x`) I would have "source", "target", and the word sequence "source and target", and on the Ordinate (`y`) the frequencies.

```
{"source", "source", "and", "target", "source", "and", "target", \
"target", "source", "and", "target", "target", "source", "and", \
"target", "target", "target", "target", "target", "source", "and", \
"target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "target", "target", \
"target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "source", "and", \
"target", "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "target", \
"target", "target", "target", "target", "target", "target", "target", \
"target", "source", "and", "target", "target", "target", "target", \
"target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "source", "and", \
"target", "source", "and", "target", "target", "target", "source", \
"and", "target", "target", "target", "target", "target", "source", \
"and", "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "source", \
"source", "and", "target", "target", "target", "source", "and", \
"target", "source", "and", "target", "source", "and", "target", \
"target", "source", "and", "target", "target", "target", "target", \
"source", "and", "target", "source", "and", "target", "target", \
"source", "and", "target", "source", "and", "target", "target", \
"target", "source", "and", "target", "target", "source", "target", \
"target", "source", "and", "target", "source", "and", "target", \
"source", "and", "target", "source", "and", "target", "source", \
"and", "target", "source", "target", "target", "source", "and", \
"target", "target", "target", "target", "target", "source", "and", \
"target", "target", "target", "source", "source", "and", "target", \
"target", "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "target", \
"target", "target", "target", "target", "target", "target", "target", \
"target", "source", "and", "target", "source", "and", "target", \
"target", "source", "and", "target", "source", "and", "target"}
```

Those are the data I want to plot!
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: [`Tally`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html) the rest is up to you

Comment: @Sektor I think it is asked to find the tallies for "source", "target", and {"source","and","target"}. Regardless if that is the case or not, the question is not phrased clearly.

Comment: Greetings @Ati! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Ati, you should clarify what you need. Is it what   Anton Antonov  says?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume it is asked to find the tallies for (1) "source", (2) "target", and (3) the sequence of words "source", "and", "target".

If that is the case this code does it.

```
words = {"source", "source", "and", "target", "source", "and", 
   "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "target", "source", 
   "and", "target", "target", "target", "target", "target", "source", 
   "and", "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "target", 
   "target", "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "source", 
   "and", "target", "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", 
   "target", "target", "target", "target", "target", "target", 
   "target", "target",  "target", "source", "and", "target", "target",
    "target", "target", "target", "target", "source", "and", "target",
    "source", "and",  "target", "source", "and", "target", "target", 
   "target", "source", "and", "target", "target", "target", "target", 
   "target", "source", "and", "target", "target", "source", "and", 
   "target", "source", "source", "and", "target", "target", "target", 
   "source", "and", "target", "source", "and", "target", "source", 
   "and", "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "target", 
   "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "source", "and", 
   "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "source", "and", 
   "target", "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "target", 
   "source", "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", "source", 
   "and", "target", "source", "and", "target", "source", "and", 
   "target", "source", "and", "target", "source", "target", "target", 
   "source", "and", "target", "target", "target", "target", "target", 
   "source", "and", "target", "target", "target", "source", "source", 
   "and", "target", "target", "target", "target", "source", "and", 
   "target", "target", "target", "target", "target", "target", 
   "target", "target", "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", 
   "source", "and", "target", "target", "source", "and", "target", 
   "source", "and", "target"};

newWords = 
 words //. {start___, "source", "and", "target", end___} :> {start, 
    "source and target", end}

BarChart[Counts[newWords], ChartLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**Update**
Since my answer was accepted I updated it with the commands in the answer by Szabolcs.

Comment: Yes, awesome! This is exactly what I was asking! Sorry about the confused question!! Thank youuuuuu!!!!!!!!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the thesis!

Answer (score 2):

```
BarChart[#2, ChartLabels -> #1] & @@ Transpose[Tally[data]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]